# In terminal CLI or shell sciprt, I want count the lines of multiple files and write the lines count on the first line at each file

Tags: linux, shell, sed, terminal, command-line-interface

In terminal CLI or shell sciprt, I want count the lines of multiple files and write the lines count on the first line at each file.

For example, a.txt, b.txt, c.txt are in a directory.

a.txt

```
hello world a_1
hello world a_2
hello world a_3
hello world a_4
```

b.txt

```
hello world b_1
hello world b_2
```

c.txt

```
hello world c_1
hello world c_2
hello world c_3
```

a.txt has 4 lines.

b.txt has 2 lines.

c.txt has 3 lines.

So, I want as follows...

a.txt

```
4 lines are in.
hello world a_1
hello world a_2
hello world a_3
hello world a_4
```

b.txt

```
2 lines are in.
hello world b_1
hello world b_2
```

c.txt

```
3 lines are in.
hello world c_1
hello world c_2
hello world c_3
```

I tried using 'sed' but I'm failed...
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could use something like this:

```
for file in *.txt; do
    printf '%d lines are in.\n' "$(wc -l < "$file")" | cat - "$file"
done
```

`wc -l` gets the number of lines. `printf` uses the number to produce a string. `cat` combines the output of `printf` with the contents of the file.

This will print to standard output. If you're happy with the output, you can add `> tmp && mv tmp "$file"` to the command inside the loop, to overwrite the original files.